# Do portable executable files encode the x86 code segment descriptor flags?

Tags: x86, x86-64, portable-executable

From my understanding of the Intel x86-64 manuals (especially Vol 3, 5.2), each code segment has flags associated with it that control how the processor treats the data/code. Of specific interest are `CS.D`, the default operand/address size bit, and `CS.L` the 64-bit mode bit, since they impact the way instructions are decoded and executed.

Are those values explicitly encoded somewhere in the PE file format, or does Windows always set the segment descriptors to `CS.D = 1, CS.L = 0` (default to 32-bit sizes) if the machine type is `i386` and `CS.D = 0, CS.L = 1` (64-bit mode) if the machine type is `AMD64`?

If the latter, is it possible to encode `CS.D = 0, CS.L = 0` (default to 16-bit sizes)?

Comment: Those are in the descriptor not in the selector. They are controlled by the OS.

Comment: @MargaretBloom I'm confused, I never mentioned selectors?

Comment: Sorry I must have misunderstood *code segment* for *code segment register/segment registers*

Comment: Anyway the OS set a predefined set of descriptors based on the execution environments (let's call them this way) it wants to support. The PE header (or the lack of it, if only an MZ header or none are present) tell the OS if the executable is meant to be run on a 32 bit environment, 64 bit or the no longer supported 16 bit V86 mode. All the programs then use these fixed set of descriptors, they are created at boot and AFAIK never changed under normal circumstances.